# How to group X axis values in 100% stacked column chart in Excel

Tags: excel, stacked-bar-chart

[Chart Screen Cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CJKC.png)

In Excel, I've created a data set, pivot table, and 100% stacked column chart.
However, I'm struggling to combine the hour values in the X axis so that it's a single bar per month with each hour value in a different color to accumulate to 100%.
What I'm getting is in the screen cap and what I'm trying to get is in my crummy drawing.

The values of the x axis (i.e. <1h, 1-4h, 4-8h, 8-24h, etc.) would be in a single stack with colors that accumulate to 100%

Comment: Your images(?) appear not to have been uploaded/included?

Comment: Thanks Chronocidal. I added the image link

Answer (score 0):

Change your Pivot Table, to have "Date" in either Rows or Columns, to have "Closed Age" in the *other* (i.e. if you have "Date" in Rows, then put "Closed Age" in Columns, and vice-verse), and have "Sum of Record Count" as your only value:

| [Sum of Record Count] | <1h | 1-4h | 4-8h | 8-24h | 24-48h | >48h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23-Aug | 1080 | 142 | 144 | 42 | 41 | 0 |
| 23-Sep | 828 | 158 | 75 | 32 | 8 | 5 |
| 23-Oct | 755 | 155 | 89 | 71 | 50 | 76 |

Then turn **that** into a Stacked Column Chart. (You may need to swap Rows/Columns afterwards)